# ObservableCollection não está populando

Tags: xamarin-forms

Quero popular um ObservableCollection para posteriormente exibir quando a tela for carregada. Dentro do meu ViewModel estou definindo os dados para teste, porém quando vou fazer o print não tem conteúdo.

Eu executo NoticeShow() quando a página / ContentPage é carregado.

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        ChannelViewModel ViewModel = new ChannelViewModel();
        ViewModel.NoticeShow();   
    }
```

Dentro do meu ViewModel

```
    public class Notice
    {
        public string NoticeMessage { get; set; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Notice> Notices; 

    public void NoticeShow()
    {
        Notices = new ObservableCollection<Notice>()
        {
            new Notice { NoticeMessage = "Teste de mensagem 1" },
            new Notice { NoticeMessage = "Teste de mensagem 2" },
            new Notice { NoticeMessage = "Teste de mensagem 3" }
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Console log -> "+Notices);                        
    }
```

Retorno do Console writeline

```
Console log -> System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[iSequi.ViewModels.ChannelViewModel+Notice]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá @RRV

No construtor da sua View você deve setar o BindingContext para a sua ViewModel:

```
public partial class MinhaView{
   public MinhaView(){
     ChannelViewModel ViewModel = new ChannelViewModel();
     BindingContext = ViewModel;
   }
}
```

Em seguida no evento `Appering`, você pode utilizar seu código:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    ViewModel.NoticeShow();   
}
```

Em seguida você deve realizar o binding do `Notices` na sua View, apenas lembrando de definir a propriedade `Notices` presente na ViewModel como pública, ao invés de privado:

```
public ObservableCollection<Notice> Notices;
```

Comment: Olá Vinicius Dutra.. Adicionei  BindingContext direto no OnAppearing,as não teve efeito.                                                                                           
       protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            ChannelViewModel ViewModel = new ChannelViewModel();
            BindingContext = ViewModel;
            ViewModel.NoticeShow();   
        }

Comment: Você definiu a propriedade `public ObservableCollection<Notice> Notices; ` como publica e realizou o bindind na view `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Notices}"> ... </ListView>` segue link com exemplo completo [https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance#custom-cells](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance#custom-cells)